# rm -rf inside container via Bitbucket pipeline

Tags: docker, filesystems, bitbucket-pipelines

we use bitbucket pipelines for our CD to Google cloud.

Among others, we build an apache image. Inside it's dockefile we have a step to remove default apache's vhosts:

```
RUN rm -rf /etc/apache2/sites-available/*
```

This worked fine until a few days ago. Now the rm stopped working and after searching we found out that it's probably due to bitbucket's filesystem which is formatted without d_type support.

See here http://www.rubyrube.com/2017/06/28/dockerfile-run-rm-not-working-ex-run-rm-rf-usrlocaltomcatwebappsroot/

*We deployed the image outside the pipeline properly, so we're sure that it's related to bitbucket.

Can you advice a workaround for this?

Comment: Is your BitBucket self-hosted or on bitbucket.com ?
The rm stopped working as in "it's ignored" or as in "the build fails" ?

Comment: It's not self-hosted unfortunately, it's on their side. rm is ignored without errors. I exec the container after the deployment and files that are supposed to be deleted are there.

Comment: Same issue here, did you manage to find a workaround?

Comment: @ThomasVdBerge not yet. I have ticketed bitbucket and they're investigating. I'm also asking in bitbucket community here https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/rm-rf-inside-container-via-Bitbucket-pipeline/qaq-p/903061?utm_source=atlcomm&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=immediate_general_answer&utm_content=topic

Comment: That was the right move. In the mean time, if really that's blocking your pipelines, you can add a temporary cleanup task as entrypoint, or depending on your runtime, directly mount an empty volume in its place. But since it's sites-available and not sites-enabled, I am not certain it would be worthwhile.